# Pass Value From JSP To JSF Page Backing Bean

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, javabeans

Is it possible to pass parameter from a JSP page to a JSF page's backing bean?

JSP page is popup window open when I invoke a button in JSF page and my selected value in JSP page, I should be able to pass to JSF's backing bean.

P.S. When I add comment and I put @anyname when someone replies, @namyname part is getting truncated.

Update 1

To get the selected value from JSP to bean I did a crude approach.

I added the the following in JSP

```
String str = request.getParameter("selectname");
```

and assigned string str to a hidden field

```
 <input type="hidden" name="hid" value="<%=str%>"  />
```

and in my bean I am getting the value like the following

```
logger.info("jsp value "+FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
               .getRequestParameterMap().get("hid"));
```

This almost works except I always gets the value which I previously selects.
E.g. First time when I selects 1 and value returned in bean is null, second time when I selects 2, value returned is 1.

How could I get the currently selected value in my bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if your JSF view technology is JSP, then you can use the `<h:>` tags in the jsp and it becomes straightforward 0 just add a `<h:commandButton action="#{yourBean.yourMethod}" />`

Otherwise, you still can perhaps, but I'd suggest that you make your popup also a JSF page. JSF and JSP don't coexist well. If you really must retain the situation, then you can try to emulate a JSF POST request to the target jsf URL.

Comment: If I could use `<h:>`, then how could I pass values to bean or to JSF? Could you be kind enough to explain more on this? Thanks

Comment: well, the regular way: `<h:commandButton action="#{bean.method}"` />

Comment: How could I pass a html select component value to bean when I click `<h:commandButton`. In action I am calling bean method, however not sure how I could pass a value from JSP.

Comment: I have added my test approach as Update 1 in my original post.

Comment: you can have the parameters as fields of the bean with setters and getters. That's the standartd aproach

Comment: could you kindly provide any example with parameters as fields of the bean? Thanks

Comment: well, I can, but this is the first thing in every tutorial, and I'm a bit busy now.

Answer (score 1):

`f:viewParam` lets you associate bean 
properties with request parameters
–

-This introduces several new capabilities

- New tags that navigate via GET instead of POST and tags that
  navigate via GET instead of POST, and send parameters along with the
  address
- Sending data from non-JSF forms to JSF pages
- Make results pages results pages  bookmarkable
- This is a new  feature in JSF 2.0
- example:
  `<f:viewParam name="fg" value="#{colorPreferences.foreground}" />`
- If the “fg” parameter is non-null, it is passed to 
  setForeground before the page is rendered

  ```
  <f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="param1" value="#{bean.prop1}"/>
  <f:viewParam name="param2" value="#{bean.prop2}"/>
  </f:metadata>
  <h:head>…</h:head>
  <h:body>
  Blah Blah blah #{bean prop1} , blah, #{bean.prop1}
  </h:body>
  ```

  If the page is called with `page.jsp?param1=foo&param2=bar`, then **“foo”** and **“bar”** are passed to **“setProp1”** and  **“setProp2”** before the page is rendered. If any of the parameters are null (i.e., no such request parameter exists), then the associated setter is not called at all, and the bean has its normal value for that property

You can find the answer from the  JSF tutorial http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/